# async Volley StringRequest in RxJava2?

Tags: android, android-volley, rx-java2

I want to fetch data from server through **Volley StringRequest** in **RxJava2**, But I could not find that how create an Observable for it.
In some articles I found that *Observable.fromCallable* is useful without any sample.
Please tell me How can I call an async Volley stringRequest with RxJava2 ??

mention:I don't want to use *Future*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the doc, http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#fromCallable(java.util.concurrent.Callable) is for wrapping synchronous request. Since `StringRequest` is asynchronous, you are looking for `Observable.create` or better in your case `Single.create`. Since it's an little advanced part of RxJava, I suggest you to look to already existing wrapper like [VolleyX](https://github.com/yangweigbh/VolleyX) or [RxVolley](https://github.com/kymjs/RxVolley) or even native RxJava alternatives to Volley.

Comment: ,I tried to use Observable.fromCallable but I could not success. please take me an example code

Comment: I completely modified my answer

Comment: ,Thanks.I used **Single.fromFuture** and **Single.fromCallable** and both them worked well.    Tell me please ,What is diffrence between them ?

Comment: Single.fromCallable wrap a synchronous function. When the observable is subscribed, it call the function and pass down the returned value, making it asynchronous in effect. Single.fromFuture transform a future in an observable, it's a just a change between two similar asynchronous paradigm.